# What does History.length class method do?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, browser-history, html5-history

I typically use `window.history` to access the `History` [web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history), however I noticed that on MDN there is are static singleton methods/properties on the global `History` object such as `History.length`.

I noticed that `History.length` returns `0` that is incorrect while `window.history.length` returns a `non-zero` value that is correct.

What is the purpose of the former? Why does it return the wrong value?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `length` property on the `History` constructor function is the same as for any function.

See [`Function.length` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length):

> The length property indicates the number of arguments expected by the function.

```js
function foo() {};
function bar(a, b, c) {};
console.log({ foo: foo.length, bar: bar.length });

console.log("History is a " + typeof History);
console.log("history is a " + typeof history);
console.log("History is the same as history? " + (History == history));
```

Comment: @Luca — See the syntax section of that page. It is talking about `history` not `History`.

Comment: Yeah, MDN confused me a little by switching between `History.length` and `history.length`

Comment: Could you add a section about why it would be usefull ? or maybe that would be offtopic

Comment: @JanWillemHuising — I've never found it useful. Interesting, but not useful.

Comment: alright, I found it interesting aswell. But i cant imagine a use for it either. thanks anyway

Comment: Interesting, this seems to directly contradict the documentation?

Comment: @AdamThompson — It doesn't contradict the documentation.

Comment: @Quentin the documentation states "Returns an Integer representing the number of elements in the session history, including the currently loaded page." To me that sounds different from the number of arguments expected by the function?

Comment: @AdamThompson — That's the documentation for `history` not `History`.

Comment: @Quentin the quote is taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

Comment: @AdamThompson — Which is the History interface, accessible via objects which implement it, like `history` which is an  instance of `History` and is not the `History` constructor function itself.

Comment: @Quentin weird, maybe I'm not used to this documentation style. If it was the object itself I would expect something like `history.length` to signify it is an instance of the class. Is it weird that it is displayed as `History.length`?

Comment: It's describing all instances of `History` of which `history` is just one (very common one)

Comment: @Quentin I see that now, but typically isn't that notation used for things like static class methods/properties/singletons? What if there was a static class property length as well, then how would it be denoted? Both would be `History.length`?

Comment: It would be on documentation about the `History` constructor function and not the `History` interface.

Comment: @Quentin why? Both are part of the interface. Interface doesn't mean instance.

Comment: instances implement interfaces, constructors do not, their output (instances) do